Spring Batch Issue with Spring Boot 3.1.X
We are using Spring Batch in our application and after upgrading the SpringBoot Version from 2.7.X (uses spring batch 4.X) to 3.1.X (uses spring batch 5.x) version we are getting the exception while running the steps.
Below are the code snippets.
ReportBatchConfiguration
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.BatchConfigurationException;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.DefaultBatchConfiguration;
import org.springframework.batch.core.explore.JobExplorer;
import org.springframework.batch.core.explore.support.JobExplorerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.TaskExecutorJobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.support.DefaultDataFieldMaxValueIncrementerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.task.TaskExecutor;
import org.springframework.scheduling.TaskScheduler;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;


@Configuration
@EnableAsync
@RequiredArgsConstructor

public class ReportBatchConfiguration extends DefaultBatchConfiguration {

    private int schedulerThreadPoolSize=5;

    private int jobThreadPoolSize=2;

    @Value("${spring.batch.jdbc.table-prefix}")
    private String tablePrefix;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

    @Bean
    @Override
    public TaskExecutorJobLauncher jobLauncher() throws BatchConfigurationException {
        TaskExecutorJobLauncher jobLauncher = new TaskExecutorJobLauncher();
        try {
            jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(getTaskExecutor());
            jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository());
            jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
            return jobLauncher;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new BatchConfigurationException("Unable to configure the default job launcher", e);
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskScheduler taskScheduler() {
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        taskScheduler.setPoolSize(schedulerThreadPoolSize);
        taskScheduler.setThreadGroupName("TaskScheduler-Report");
        taskScheduler.afterPropertiesSet();
        return taskScheduler;

    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public TaskExecutor getTaskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        taskExecutor.setPoolSize(jobThreadPoolSize);
        taskExecutor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
        taskExecutor.setThreadGroupName("TaskExecutor-Report");
        taskExecutor.initialize();
        return taskExecutor;

    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public JobRepository jobRepository() throws BatchConfigurationException {
        JobRepositoryFactoryBean jobRepositoryFactoryBean = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();

        try {
            jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
            jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
            jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setDatabaseType("DB2");
            jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setTablePrefix(tablePrefix);
            DefaultDataFieldMaxValueIncrementerFactory incrementerFactory = new DefaultDataFieldMaxValueIncrementerFactory(dataSource);
            jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setIncrementerFactory(incrementerFactory);
            jobRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();

            return jobRepositoryFactoryBean.getObject();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new BatchConfigurationException("Unable to configure the default job repository", e);
        }
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public JobExplorer jobExplorer() throws BatchConfigurationException {
        JobExplorerFactoryBean jobExplorerFactoryBean = new JobExplorerFactoryBean();

        try {
            jobExplorerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
            jobExplorerFactoryBean.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
            jobExplorerFactoryBean.setTablePrefix(tablePrefix);
            jobExplorerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();

            return jobExplorerFactoryBean.getObject();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new BatchConfigurationException("Unable to configure the default job explorer", e);
        }
    }
}

ReportService
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.commons.collections4.CollectionUtils;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook;
import org.springframework.batch.core.job.builder.SimpleJobBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParametersBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParametersInvalidException;
import org.springframework.batch.core.job.builder.JobBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.RunIdIncrementer;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.TaskExecutorJobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRestartException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Service
@Slf4j
public class ReportService {

    private TaskExecutorJobLauncher jobLauncher;

    private ReportJobCompletionListener listener;

    private ReportRepository reportRepo;

    private ReportStepFactory stepFactory;

    private JobRepository jobRepository;

    public ReportService(TaskExecutorJobLauncher jobLauncher,
                               ReportJobCompletionListener listener, ReportRepository reportRepo,
                               ReportStepFactory stepFactory, JobRepository jobRepository) {
        this.jobLauncher = jobLauncher;
        this.listener = listener;
        this.reportRepo = reportRepo;
        this.stepFactory = stepFactory;
        this.jobRepository = jobRepository;
    }

    public void getBMPCompletedJobs() {

    
            try {

                List<ReportMessageData> reportMessageDataList = reportRepo.getBMPCompletedJobs();
                

                if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(reportMessageDataList)) {
                    reportMessageDataList.forEach(reportMessageData -> {
                        try {
                            ReportMetaData reportMetaData = ReportGenerationUtil.getReportMetaData(reportMessageData);
                            log.info("The Report Code {} taken up for batch processing", reportMetaData.getRptCode());
                            Job job = createJob(reportMetaData);
                            
                            JobParameters jobParm = new JobParametersBuilder()
                                    .addString("reportMetaData", reportMetaData.toString())
                                    .addDate("date", new Date())
                                    .toJobParameters();
                            
                            JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(job, jobParm);
                            log.info("The Job Execution status of Job Name: {} is {}",
                                    jobExecution.getJobInstance().getJobName(), jobExecution.getStatus());

                        } catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException | JobRestartException
                                 | JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException | JobParametersInvalidException e) {
                            log.error("There is an error in running the Job. The error message: ", e);
                        }
                    });

                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                log.error("There is a error in getting BMP completed jobs", ex);
            }
        

    }

    private Job createJob(ReportMetaData reportMetaData) {

        SimpleJobBuilder simpleBuilder = null;

        JobBuilder jobBuilder = new JobBuilder(reportMetaData.getRptCode(), jobRepository).incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(listener);

        simpleBuilder = jobBuilder.start(stepFactory.getStep(reportMetaData.getRptCode()));
        
        return simpleBuilder.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, SXSSFWorkbook> intializeWorkbookMap() {
        return new HashMap<>();
    }

}

EmissionReportItemWriter
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HeaderFooter;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Footer;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepScope;
import org.springframework.batch.item.Chunk;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Component(ReportCodeConstants.EMISSION_REPORT_CODE + "itemWriter")
@StepScope
@Slf4j
public class EmissionReportItemWriter extends EmissionXSSFReportWriter implements ItemWriter<EmissionReport> {

    private List<EmissionReport> emissionReportList;

    @Value("#{jobParameters['reportMetaData']}")
    private ReportMetaData reportMetaData;

    @Override
    public void write(Chunk<? extends EmissionReport> items) throws Exception {
        emissionReportList = new ArrayList<>((Collection) items);
        this.createReport(reportMetaData);
    }

    @Override
    public void createWorksheet(SXSSFWorkbook wb, ReportMetaData metaData) throws EmissionReportException {

        initializeWorkbook(wb);
        SXSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Emission Report");

        try {
            StringBuilder headerTitle = new StringBuilder();
            headerTitle.append(reportMetaData.getAgencyDesc());
            headerTitle.append("\n");
            headerTitle.append("QUARTER ENDING " + reportMetaData.getPeriodEndingDate());
            headerTitle.append("\n");
            createProfile(sheet, headerTitle.toString());
            
            createFooter(sheet);

            List<ExcelConfig> emissionConfigList = loadConfigFile(ReportCodeConstants.EMISSION_REPORT_CODE);
            
            setColumnWidth(sheet, emissionConfigList);

            setColumnHeader(sheet, emissionConfigList);

            setCustomRowData(sheet, emissionConfigList, emissionReportList);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Emission Report: Error in creating the report {}", e.getMessage());
            throw new EmissionReportException("Emission Report ERROR: Error in creating the report", e);
        }

    }
    
    public void setCustomRowData(SXSSFSheet sheet, List<ExcelConfig> configList,
            List<EmissionReport> emissionReportList) {
        log.info("The no. of records received to create report {} : {}", sheet.getSheetName(),
                emissionReportList.size());
        emissionReportList.stream().forEach(emissionReport -> {
            SXSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(getRowPos());
            setColumnData(row, emissionReport, configList);
            addAdditionalRows(sheet, emissionReport);
            setRowPos(getRowPos() + 1);
        });
        setRowPos(0);
    }
    
    private void addAdditionalRows(SXSSFSheet sheet, EmissionReport emissionReport) {
        setRowPos(getRowPos() + 1);
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(emissionReport.getLocalFSADescription())) {
            SXSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(getRowPos());
            this.createCell(row, this.dataFont, 1, "**" + emissionReport.getLocalFSADescription(), StringUtils.EMPTY,
                    CellType.STRING, this.leftStyle);
            setRowPos(getRowPos() + 1);
        }
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(emissionReport.getEndNote())) {
            SXSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(getRowPos());
            this.createCell(row, this.dataFont, 0, "**" + emissionReport.getEndNote(), StringUtils.EMPTY,
                    CellType.STRING, this.leftStyle);
            setRowPos(getRowPos() + 1);
        }
    }
    
    private void createFooter(SXSSFSheet sheet) {
         
        Footer footer = sheet.getFooter();
        
        //set the left footer into the sheet.
        footer.setLeft(
                HeaderFooter.font(ReportConstants.DEF_FONT_FACE, ReportConstants.DEF_FONT_STYLE)
                + HeaderFooter.fontSize(ReportConstants.DEF_FONT_SIZE)
                + ReportConstants.EM_RPT_LEFT_FOOTER
                );

        //set the page numbers into the footer
        StringBuilder rightFooter = new StringBuilder();
        rightFooter.append("Generated: " + LocalDate.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy")));
        rightFooter.append(ReportConstants.NEW_LINE);
        rightFooter.append("Page ");
        rightFooter.append(HeaderFooter.page());
        rightFooter.append(" of ");
        rightFooter.append(HeaderFooter.numPages());
        
        //set the right footer      
        footer.setRight(
            HeaderFooter.font(ReportConstants.DEF_FONT_FACE, ReportConstants.DEF_FONT_STYLE)
                + HeaderFooter.fontSize(ReportConstants.DEF_FONT_SIZE)
                + rightFooter.toString());

    }

}


ReportItemReaderConfiguration
import java.sql.Types;
import java.util.Optional;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepScope;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.StoredProcedureItemReader;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlOutParameter;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlParameter;


@Configuration(enforceUniqueMethods = false)
public class ReportItemReaderConfiguration {

    private DataSource dataSource;

    private ReportPreparedStatementSetter preparedStatementSetter;

    public ReportItemReaderConfiguration(@Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource,
            ReportPreparedStatementSetter preparedStatementSetter) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
        this.preparedStatementSetter = preparedStatementSetter;
    }

    
    @Bean(ReportCodeConstants.EMISSION_REPORT_CODE + ReportConstants.READER_NAME_SUFFIX)
    @StepScope
    public StoredProcedureItemReader<EmissionReport> getEmissionItemReader(
            EmissionReportRowMapper emissionReportRowMapper) {
        StoredProcedureItemReader<EmissionReport> emissionReport = new StoredProcedureItemReader<>();
        emissionReport.setRowMapper(emissionReportRowMapper);
        setCommonValues(emissionReport, ReportConstants.EMISSION_REPORT_STORE_PROC);
        return emissionReport;
    }
    
    private void setCommonValues(StoredProcedureItemReader<?> itemReader, String procedureName) {
        SqlParameter[] parameters = { new SqlParameter(CommonConstants.INPUT_PARM1, Types.VARCHAR) };
        Optional<DataSource> readerDataSource = Optional.of(dataSource);
        itemReader.setProcedureName(procedureName);
        itemReader.setDataSource(readerDataSource.get());
        itemReader.setParameters(parameters);
        itemReader.setPreparedStatementSetter(preparedStatementSetter);
        itemReader.setFetchSize(ReportConstants.FETCH_SIZE);
        itemReader.setVerifyCursorPosition(false);
    }

}


ReportPreparedStatementSetter

import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Types;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepScope;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementSetter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Component
@StepScope
@Slf4j
public class ReportPreparedStatementSetter implements PreparedStatementSetter {

    @Value("#{jobParameters['reportMetaData']}")
    private ReportMetaData reportMetaData;
    
    @Override
    public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {

        String inputParm = StringUtils.EMPTY;
        String reportCode = reportMetaData.getRptCode();

        inputParm = setEmissionReportValue();
        
        ps.setString(1, inputParm);
    }

    public void setReportMetaData(ReportMetaData reportMetaData) {
        this.reportMetaData = reportMetaData;
    }
    
    private String setEmissionReportValue() {
        StringBuilder emissionParam = new StringBuilder();
        emissionParam.append(LaunchUtil.fillWithZeros(reportMetaData.getReportId(), 9));
        emissionParam.append(LaunchUtil.fillWithZeros(reportMetaData.getJobQue(), 9));
        emissionParam.append(LaunchUtil.fillWithSpace(reportMetaData.getAgencyCode(), 5));
        emissionParam.append(LaunchUtil.fillWithSpace(reportMetaData.getHubCode(), 2));
        emissionParam.append(LaunchUtil.fillWithSpace(reportMetaData.getCountryCode(), 3));
        log.info("INPUT PARAM ONE to read data for Emission Report Id: {} and Report Code: {} is: {}",
                reportMetaData.getReportId(), this.reportMetaData.getRptCode(), emissionParam);
        return emissionParam.toString();
    }

}

ReportStepFactory
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository;
import org.springframework.batch.core.step.builder.StepBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

@Component
public class ReportStepFactory {

    private final BeanFactory beanFactory;


    private JobRepository jobRepository;

    private PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager;

    private ReportExceptionHandler exceptionHandler;

    private ReportStepResultListener stepListener;

    private LaunchCompositeReportWriterTasklet compositeWriterTasklet;

    public ReportStepFactory(BeanFactory beanFactory,
            ReportExceptionHandler exceptionHandler, ReportStepResultListener stepListener,
            LaunchCompositeReportWriterTasklet compositeWriterTasklet, JobRepository jobRepository, @Qualifier("jpaDb2TransactionManager") PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager) {
        this.beanFactory = beanFactory;
        this.exceptionHandler = exceptionHandler;
        this.stepListener = stepListener;
        this.compositeWriterTasklet = compositeWriterTasklet;
        this.jobRepository = jobRepository;
        this.platformTransactionManager = platformTransactionManager;
    }

    public Step getStep(String reportCode) {
        
            return getReportStep(reportCode);
        
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Step getReportStep(String reportCode) {
        String beanName = reportCode + ReportConstants.READER_NAME_SUFFIX;
        return new StepBuilder(reportCode, jobRepository)
                .chunk(ReportConstants.FETCH_SIZE, platformTransactionManager)
                .reader((ItemReader<? extends Object>) beanFactory.getBean(beanName))
                .writer((ItemWriter<? super Object>) beanFactory.getBean(reportCode + ReportConstants.WRITER_NAME_SUFFIX))
                .faultTolerant()
                .retryLimit(3)
                .retry(IllegalStateException.class)
                .retry(SQLException.class)
                .retry(com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException.class)
                .retry(SqlSyntaxErrorException.class)
                .retry(SQLTransientConnectionException.class)
                .exceptionHandler(exceptionHandler)
                .listener(stepListener)
                .build();
    }

}


ReportStepResultListener
import java.util.Collections;

import org.springframework.batch.core.ExitStatus;
import org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecutionListener;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepScope;
import org.springframework.batch.item.Chunk;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ScopedProxyMode;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Component
@StepScope
@Slf4j
public class ReportStepResultListener implements StepExecutionListener {

    @Value("#{jobParameters['reportMetaData']}")
    private ReportMetaData reportMetaData;

    private final BeanFactory beanFactory;

    public ReportStepResultListener(BeanFactory beanFactory) {
        super();
        this.beanFactory = beanFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        log.info("The Step has started for the report code {}", reportMetaData.getRptCode());
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        if ((stepExecution.getReadCount() == 0 && ExitStatus.COMPLETED.equals(stepExecution.getExitStatus()))) {
            ItemWriter<? super Object> itemWriter = (ItemWriter<? super Object>) beanFactory
                    .getBean(reportMetaData.getRptCode() + ReportConstants.WRITER_NAME_SUFFIX);
            try {
                itemWriter.write((Chunk<?>) Collections.emptyList());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Error in creating empty report for the report code: {} and trace: {}",
                        reportMetaData.getRptCode(), e);
                return ExitStatus.FAILED;
            }
        }

        return ExitStatus.COMPLETED;
    }

}


Stack Trace of the Exception
2024-09-19 16:23:03,312 [getTaskExecutor-1][transactionId=] ERROR AbstractJob Encountered fatal error executing job
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [INSERT INTO <OUR_SCHEMA_NAME>_BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION(STEP_EXECUTION_ID, VERSION, STEP_NAME, JOB_EXECUTION_ID, START_TIME, END_TIME, STATUS, COMMIT_COUNT, READ_COUNT, FILTER_COUNT, WRITE_COUNT, EXIT_CODE, EXIT_MESSAGE, READ_SKIP_COUNT, WRITE_SKIP_COUNT, PROCESS_SKIP_COUNT, ROLLBACK_COUNT, LAST_UPDATED, CREATE_TIME)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
]; DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-407, SQLSTATE=23502, SQLERRMC=*N, DRIVER=4.33.31
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.doTranslate(SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.java:97)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1572)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:667)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:960)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:1015)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:1020)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcStepExecutionDao.saveStepExecution(JdbcStepExecutionDao.java:159)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.add(SimpleJobRepository.java:209)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:391)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:244)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy196.add(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:147)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.handleStep(AbstractJob.java:418)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob.doExecute(SimpleJob.java:132)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:317)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:157)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:577)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:317)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlIntegrityConstraintViolationException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-407, SQLSTATE=23502, SQLERRMC=*N, DRIVER=4.33.31
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.b4.a(b4.java:806)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.b4.a(b4.java:66)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.b4.a(b4.java:140)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kn.b(kn.java:2515)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kn.c(kn.java:2496)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.aa.n(aa.java:933)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.aa.a(aa.java:116)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.p.a(p.java:50)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.av.b(av.java:224)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ko.bm(ko.java:3778)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ko.a(ko.java:4825)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ko.b(ko.java:4361)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ko.be(ko.java:836)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ko.executeUpdate(ko.java:810)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.lambda$update$2(JdbcTemplate.java:965)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:648)
    ... 29 common frames omitted
2024-09-19 16:23:05,450 [getTaskExecutor-1][transactionId=] INFO  SimpleJobLauncher$1 Job: [SimpleJob: [name=EM]] completed with the following parameters: [{'date':'{value=Thu Sep 19 16:21:51 IST 2024, type=class java.util.Date, identifying=true}','reportMetaData':'{value=ReportMetaData(processIndicator=null, rptId=74301, rptCode=EM), type=class java.lang.String, identifying=true}'}] and the following status: [FAILED] in 6s470ms

Note: I am not using @EnableBatchProcessing since we are explicitly setting the DataSource, Table Prefix, TransactionManager etc so using ReportBatchConfiguration class which extends DefaultBatchConfiguration class.
Database: DB2
I have also altered the Spring Batch core tables and created the sequence as mentioned in the migration guide - Spring Batch 5.0 migration guide
Can someone help me to fix this issue?

DefaultBatchConfiguration imports the class where batch scopes are defined. So i don't think this issue is due to the step scope being misconfigured or not defined.
DataIntegrityViolationException seems related to something else. Please share the full stacktrace of the error or a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to help you efficiently.

I agree with you @Mahmoud that this issue is not due to the step scope. While debugging I don't find any issue with the job execution tables. It's failing during the step execution. Added the stack trace for your reference.

Thank you for the update. I can't see from what you shared what could cause this issue. If you manage to create a minimal example, I can try to debug the case.

I have added the code snippets as requested. Hope this helps you to look further into the issue.

I still can't see with a static code analysis the cause of the issue. Please take some time to gather all code snippets with a pom.xml in a github repo or a zip that I get clone/unzip and run to debug the case. thank you.

This issue can be closed since this exception is due to the error in table creation where the Not Null constraint was set incorrectly for one of the columns in BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION table.

Please add an answer and explain the root cause. This can help others.
